# JXL rename a sheet

Tags: java, jxl

Hi I have a template excel which I load and would like to change a sheet name in that.

```
WritableWorkbook workbook = jxl.Workbook.createWorkbook(file1,template);
```

This workbook has n sheets. I would like to change the name of a single sheet. Incase of remove there is a method called

```
workbook.removeSheet(<sheet index>)
```

I dont find any such direct method for rename.

Can someone help me in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No direct method seems to exist. I'd try a [copySheet(oldName, newName,newIndex)](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/write/WritableWorkbook.html#copySheet%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29) followed by a [removeSheet(oldIndex)](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/write/WritableWorkbook.html#removeSheet%28int%29)

Answer (score 2):

```
workbook.createSheet("Name", i);
WritableSheet excelSheet = workbook.getSheet(i);
```

and to modify the name

```
excelSheet.setName("new name");
```